# How to import another python script with HTML code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 scripts. One is my main.py script where it will call my other script to print an HTML page. The second script is html_pages.py. I'm trying to print an HTML page by importing html_pages.py and calling the welcome_page or login_page function.

Whenever I try to reach the page it says "Internal error". This was working previously when I had the login_page and welcome_page as a string stored in the main script. But it doesn't work when I try to call the function from a different script.

my main.py script contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import html_pages
if "HTTP_COOKIE" in os.environ :
    cookie_info = os.environ["HTTP_COOKIE"]
    cookies = cookie_info.split(';')
    for cookie in cookies:
    cookie_split = cookie.split('=')
    cookie_dict[cookie_split[0].strip()] = cookie_split[1].strip()
    CookieUsername = cookie_dict.get('username')
    CookiePassword = cookie_dict.get('password')
    CookieToken = cookie_dict.get('CSRFtoken')
    #Connect to the database
    import pymysql
    conn = pymysql.connect(db='project2', user='algarcia1', passwd='root',  host='localhost')
    c = conn.cursor()
    #Collect info about the user
    query = "SELECT * FROM bank WHERE username='{CookieUsername}'"
    c.execute(query.format(CookieUsername=CookieUsername))
    conn.commit()
    user = c.fetchone()
    print(html_pages.welcome_page(user[0],user[3],user[4]))
else:
    cookie_dict["username"] = "undefined"
    cookie_dict["password"] = "undefined"
    print(html_pages.login_page())
```

My HTML_pages.py script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#Create a login HTML page

def login_page(status):

    loginpage = """Content-Type: text/html

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- HTML code to send a POST request to login.py -->
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Safe Bank Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="login.py" method="POST">
            <h1>Safe Bank Website</h1>
            <strong>Username:</strong><br>
            <input type="text" name="username"><br>
            <strong>Password:</strong><br>
            <input type="text" name="password"><br>
            <strong>CSRF token:</strong><br>
            <input type="text" name="CSRFtoken"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>"""
    print(login_page.format())

def welcome_page(username, chequings, savings):
    #Create a welcome HTML page
    welcomepage = """Content-Type: text/html

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {{ border: 2px solid black; text-align: left;}}
    th, td {{ padding: 5px; }}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>Welcome {cookie_info}!</h2>

    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Chequings</th>
            <th>Savings</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{chequings}</td>
            <td>{savings}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="http://localhost/srt311/project2         /transfer_form.py">Transfer money</a>

    </body>
    </html>"""
            print(welcome_page.format(cookie_info=username,chequings=chequings,savings=savings))
```

Comment: Ok and what have you tried so far? Where is your problem?

Comment: I've tried print(html_pages.welcome_page(user[0],user[3],user[4])) and I've tried it without the print function. The problem is that I'm unable to load the page with my desired HTML code

Answer (score 0):

There are so many good python Web-Frameworks like [Flask](https://www.palletsprojects.com/p/flask/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). That make it easy so build webpages in a secure way. Especially Flask is very easy to use. Try them out and look how such frameworks do it.

In most cases it's more solid for future use to use a framework where you have a good structure.